# Draggable components

Tags: java, swing, drag-and-drop, awt

My problem is how I could create a draggable environment of objects (JPanel, JButton, etc.) so that I wouldn't able to utilize the FlowLayout class which displays the client in an orderly manner. What class and methods I am to use?
What implementation I am going to use to save the configuration? What file format I am going to use?

To visualize further this problem, the system I am trying to develop is a classroom management system wherein the room administrator will configure the environment to a seat plan like diagram.

Answer (score 3):

See [Drag Layout](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2011/10/23/drag-layout/) for a layout manager and [Component Mover](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/06/14/moving-windows/) for a class that allows you to drag components.

Answer (score 1):

This is broad stated question.

I would suggest you will need to look at...

- [How to use Layered Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/layeredpane.html) to overcome not needing a layout manager...
- [Introduction to DnD](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/dnd/intro.html) or [How to Write a Mouse Listener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/mouselistener.html) depending at what level of interaction you're looking for
- [Java API for XML Processing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxp/TOC.html) and possibly even [Java Architecture for XML Binding](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jaxb/TOC.html) or even [Preferences](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/Preferences.html)